# Proving scalar multiplication for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V$ is a vector space of positive real numbers with vector addition being defined as regular multiplication and scalar multiplication defined with the following

$$a \times v = v^a$$

The answer key says that this is a vector space but I can't seem to prove the following axiom

$$a(v+w) = av + aw$$

which turns to the following

$$(v+w)^a = v^a + w^a$$

I don't know if there is an identity that makes this true for all positive $v$ and $w$ but I can't seem to prove this holds. Is there something I'm missing?

Edit: I got it $v+w$ becomes $vw$ so 
$$a(v+w) = av + aw$$

becomes

$$(vw)^a = (v^a)(w^a)$$

and it hold, all good now, I'm just blind

Comment: The addition of the vector space is ordinary multiplication, so the distributive law turns into $(vw)^a = v^aw^a$